# Detect end of Youtube video inside the Youtube website in Javascript

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, greasemonkey

I want to detect the end of a YouTube video I am watching on the YouTube website with JavaScript.

I know they have an API for that, I tried to loaded it in the page with GreaseMonkey, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe the API is only for embedded videos on other websites?

Here is what I have so far:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("&enablejsapi=1") == -1)
  {
    window.location = window.location.href + "&enablejsapi=1";
  }

var api = document.createElement('script');
api.type = 'text/javascript';
api.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
document.body.appendChild(api);

var onFinish = document.createElement('script');
onFinish.type = 'text/javascript';
var onFinishContent = "function onPlayerStateChange(event) { console.log('test'); if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) { console.log('end'); } }"
var textNode = document.createTextNode(onFinishContent);
onFinish.appendChild(textNode);
document.body.appendChild(onFinish);

function onPlayerStateChange(event)
{
  console.log("test");
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED)
    {
      console.log("end");
    }
}
```

Like you can see, I tried to make the `onPlayerStateChange` function callable in two ways, one directly with Greasemonkey, and the second one by injecting a script node. Both of them doesn't work, I never see the "test" message I display in the console.

Does anyone know why I can't seem to be able to load the API?

Comment: A simple `document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('ended',function(){alert('Video ended!');});` should be perfectly sufficient _if_ you’re using the HTML5 player.

Comment: Is anything playing to start with? I don't see where you're creating the player. `player = new YT.Player('player', { height: '390', width: '640', playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1 }, events: {  'onReady': onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}});` and attaching the event listeners...

Comment: @Xufox Yeah, it works! Thank you, the solution was really simple in the end. 

NewToJS: the Youtube player already have the ID player to hook the api, so I assumed it was already hooked, but I might be wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian Simon's comment-answer in the year 2015:

```
document.querySelector("video").addEventListener("ended",
    () => alert("Video ended!")
);
```

I checked that this still works in the year 2022.